# FrameLayout stops ViewPager.OnTouchListener being invoked.. why?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

My `OnTouchListener` for my `ViewPager` is never invoked when I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpPages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- If I remove this, everything is fine -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navDrawerRoot"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and the following code in my activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        vpPages.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            Log.e("TAG", "Touched")
            false
        }
    }
```

If I remove the `FrameLayout` the `OnTouchListener` is invoked as expected. Can anyone explain why? And what I can do to the `FrameLayout` so that it doesn't interfere with the `ViewPager`'s touches?

Comment: can you try adding an onTouchListner to the frame and check if it's being invoked?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I added an `OnTouchListener` to `navDrawerRoot` and it doesn't get hit either.

Comment: I had to override `dispatchTouchEvent` in the end and that worked. Not fully sure I understand why, but at least I can get on with it now :)

Comment: Please, use layout inspector and see if the frame covers other layouts